# Sending data in draft by going in previous page or leaving current page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I am making a website like yahoo mailing system, there I need to make draft messages, I want as soon as a person writes in any field and when he leaves the page with out submitting that form this form gets saved in the array of drafts msgs, please guid me I am using react js for frontend

I did try using useeffect to do it by useeffect gets worked just by coming this page so it's no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just useEffect is not enough, you will need to have also component state (useState). Then on every input change update the state and also the draft messages array (you probably need to make post request for this one). Something like this:

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
  //if there is draft message, get it and set it in state
}, []);

const onInputChange = (val) => {
  setMessage(val);
  //set your message to drafts and remove it from there as soon as it is submitted
}

<input onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e.target.value)} />
```

Comment: Thank you very much , is it possible to use same function onInputChange  for different inputs?

Comment: Sure, as long as you pass the required props and need the same logic you can reuse the function within the component as much as you want. If you need to use the function in different components - you can either move it in parent component and pass it to the components that will use or even better move it in some kind of utils folder, export it from there and import it where you need it.